# Excluding some commands from getting stored in bash history only after terminal is closed

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, bash-history

Currently I am using `$HISTIGNORE` to ignore some commands and not save them in bash history. But current behaviour is if I am running a terminal I executed a command which is in `$HISTIGNORE` then on hitting up arrow it takes me to last saved command but I want to have these ignored commands available in current session and delete them only after the session is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to delete lines from your `~/.bash_history` file, e.g.

```
sed -i -e '/ apt /d' -e '/^xterm/d' ~/.bash_history
```

to delete every line containing “ apt ” and every line beginning with “xterm”.

If you want to perform the deletion every time you open a new terminal, add the `sed` line to your `~/.bashrc` file.  You can also use cron (`crontab -e`) to automate the cleanup, e.g. with the line

```
@hourly sed -i -e '/ apt /d' -e '/^xterm/d' ~/.bash_history
```

to perform the cleanup hourly.

Comment: Thanks man its really helpful but, Can I do the deletion of lines when terminal is killed and only for the commands typed in current session of terminal?

Comment: @ksmukta I searched for a way to delete the lines automatically when a terminal is closed, but I couldn't find anything useful in this case. You can do the deletion whenever you want and it will delete all matched lines in the file – what's the use of restrict it to the current session's commands?

Comment: @ksmukta You may find the [Bash History Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-History-Builtins) chapter of the Bash Reference Manual interesting.